# Multiple Commands Produce in Xcode 14 when archiving Flutter App

Tags: flutter, xcode

I got few errors when trying to archive my product in XCode 14.
This is how the error looks like.
I have tried solutions like change the podfile installations and make sure there's not duplicate file in the build phase.

[image]